# How to remove the border from a entry control with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to remove the border from a entry box with xamarin control for the following control.

```
<Entry Text="" />
```

[image]

Currently I'm seeing a thin border against the textbox, where i'm not seeing any border property to remove.

Please let me know, how to disable this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There some properties of controls that you cannot manipulate via Xamarin.Forms, you'll have to implement either an [effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/) or a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/). An effect might well do in your case, but since I'm more proficient with custom renderers, I'll show you how to achieve what you want with a custom renderer.

You'll have to create a class deriving from `EntryRenderer` that overrides `OnElementChanged`

```cs
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.Control.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 8, this.Control.Frame.Height));
        this.Control.RightView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 8, this.Control.Frame.Height));
        this.Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
        this.Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

        this.Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        this.Element.HeightRequest = 30;
    }
}
```

First there are some paddings added to the control (it looks quite ugly otherwise) by setting the `LeftView` and the `RightView` of the native control. Anyway, the more interesting part ist the `BorderStyle` by setting this property of the native control you can remove the border of the control.

Last thing you'll have to do is to say Xamarin.Forms to use that renderer. Use the following attribute in the global scope of your file (out of the namespace declaration):

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
```

If you don't want the style to be applied to *all* entries, you'll have to define a `CustomEntry` class that derives from `Entry` in your Xamarin.Forms project change the line presented above to

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
```

**Please note:** This is the iOS implementation, but basically it's the same for Android.

Comment: Is it possible to change the border color of an entry? Been struggling for a week now. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Add this class to `MainActivity.cs` of **Android** project :

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.OldElement == null)
        {
            Control.Background = null;

            var lp = new MarginLayoutParams(Control.LayoutParameters);
            lp.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            LayoutParameters = lp;
            Control.LayoutParameters = lp;
            Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        }
}
```

and add this line before namespace:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
```

then for **iOS** add this class to `Main.cs` :

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
        Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

and :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(App1.iOS.CustomEntryRenderer))]
```

for set this change only for spicial class or custum Entry, just change `typeof(Entry)` to `typeof(MyEntry)`.

Comment: Excellent! This is just what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the other responses that this is not possible with Entry unfortunately without using Effects or CustomRenderers.

My PCL-only approach was to use an **Editor** instead as this has a slightly richer set of styles and no annoying borders.  The only extra code you need to write is a TextChanged event handler to catch the user pressing "enter" which just created a new line in an Editor.  Eventhandling code as follows:

```
        searchBox.Completed += (s, e) => {
            DoSearch();
        };
        // Check for return pressed as well as we are now using an Editor
        searchBox.TextChanged += (s, e) => {
            if (e.NewTextValue.EndsWith("\n") == true) {
                // trim the text
                searchBox.Text = searchBox.Text.Trim();
                // unfocus the box
                searchBox.Unfocus();
                // search
                DoSearch();
            }
        };
```

Hope this helps - and for reference Xamarin, this has been annoying for years - please expose the borders of Entry field in a near future update!

Answer (score 1):

There are no such property to remove border in entry. if you want to remove it you have to make renderer. [Please Refer this Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)