# Remove rounded corners on TextEntry in Xamarin.iOS with Xamarin Effect

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, uikit

Having a Xamarin.Forms application with a TextEntry. It's rendered like this on iOS:

[image]

I'm trying to remove the rounded corners. Therfore I added the following Effect in the iOS project:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Effects")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(EntryWithClearButtonEffect), "EntryWithClearButtonEffect")]
namespace C4S.MobileApp.iOS.Effects
{
    public class EntryWithClearButtonEffect : PlatformEffect
    {

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            ConfigureControl();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }

        private void ConfigureControl()
        {
           var uiTextField = ((UITextField)Control);

           //Add iOS specific "clear button" to TextEntry
           uiTextField.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;

           //Excpect to remove rounded corners
           uiTextField.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And make use of it in the shared project:

```
<Entry x:Name="SearchEntry" VerticalOptions="End" Placeholder="Suchen..." ReturnType="Done" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
               Focused="VisualElement_OnFocused"  Completed="Entry_OnCompleted" TextChanged="Entry_OnCompleted">
      <Entry.Effects>
             <customControls:EntryWithClearButton />
      </Entry.Effects>
</Entry>
```

Unfortunately the rounded corners are still present. Also tried adding the following code to ConfigureControl():

```
        uiTextField.ClipsToBounds = true;
        uiTextField.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
```

Also no effect.
Setting the [UITextField.BorderStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619624-borderstyle) to None removes the whole border. That's not what I want.

**Edit:**

This is how the TextEntry looks like with the supposed `CustomRenderer` from Lucas Zhang - MSFT:

[image]

Rectengular shaped borders are present, but unfortunately the rounded corners too. By the way, I tested with the `CustomRenderer` and my above `Effect`. No difference. I think using an `Effect` is the better option here (see [Why Use an Effect over a Custom Renderer?](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction#Why_Use_an_Effect_over_a_Custom_Renderer)
).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a workaround!

Remove the border. This will also remove padding, so make sure adding some to the left and right. ([Source from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095961/how-to-remove-the-border-from-a-entry-control-with-xamarin-forms))

```
private void ConfigureControl()
{
   var uiTextField = ((UITextField)Control);

   //Add padding left and right (UITextBorderStyle.None removes padding)
   uiTextField.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 8, this.Control.Frame.Height));
   uiTextField.RightView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 8, this.Control.Frame.Height));
   uiTextField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
   uiTextField.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

   //remove border
   uiTextField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
 }
```

Add a BoxView above the text entry.

```
<BoxView HeightRequest="0.4" Color="#A9ABAC" />    
<Entry x:Name="SearchEntry" VerticalOptions="End" Placeholder="Suchen..." ReturnType="Done" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
               Focused="VisualElement_OnFocused"  Completed="Entry_OnCompleted" TextChanged="Entry_OnCompleted">
      <Entry.Effects>
             <customControls:EntryWithClearButton />
      </Entry.Effects>
</Entry>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will remove round corners

Refer link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uitextborderstyle?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

```
 uiTextField. UITextBorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
```

Comment: But it removes the whole border. I wanna keep it but without roounded corners.

Comment: You can use background image that looks similar.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uitextfield.background?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UITextField_Background

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CustomRenderer`

> in iOS project

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using App7;
using App7.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace App7.iOS
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer:EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
                Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

```
<Entry x:Name="SearchEntry" VerticalOptions="End" Placeholder="Suchen..." ReturnType="Done" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
               Focused="VisualElement_OnFocused"  Completed="Entry_OnCompleted" TextChanged="Entry_OnCompleted">

</Entry>
```

Comment: Please look at my edit. Unfortunately that's not a solution.

Comment: OK,I will check it.